# Include the integration runtime name as a parameter in the ARM Template of Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I developed a CI/CD to deploy the content (pipelines, Global parameters, LinkedServices...) of a DEV Data Factory in a PROD Data Factory.

I use 2 shirs for the DEV and PROD environments where each environment uses its own shir.

When I publish content from the DEV Data Factory which is connected to an Azure DevOps repository, I generate the `ARMTemplateForFactory.json` and `ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json` files

The problem is that the name of the shir, by default is not a parameter of the `ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json` file

I would like to include the name of the integration runtime (shir) used in each environment as a parameter of the generated ARM Template when publishing.

After some research I found that you could modify the structure of the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` file to customize the settings of the ARM Template. However, I don't know what Syntax used to do so: /

So my question is: how to include the name of the integration runtime as a parameter of the ARM Template.

Thanks a lot !

[image]

This is the json description of my integration runtime :

```
{
    "name": "TestRuntimeSam",
    "properties": {
        "type": "Managed",
        "typeProperties": {
            "computeProperties": {
                "location": "AutoResolve",
                "dataFlowProperties": {
                    "computeType": "General",
                    "coreCount": 8,
                    "timeToLive": 10,
                    "cleanup": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the basic content of the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` file :

```
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
        "properties": {
            "globalParameters": {
                "*": {
                    "value": "="
                }
            },
            "globalConfigurations": {
                "*": "="
            },
            "encryption": {
                "*": "=",
                "identity": {
                    "*": "="
                }
            }
        },
        "location": "=",
        "identity": {
            "type": "=",
            "userAssignedIdentities": "="
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {},
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes": {
        "properties": {
            "typeProperties": {
                "ssisProperties": {
                    "catalogInfo": {
                        "catalogServerEndpoint": "=",
                        "catalogAdminUserName": "=",
                        "catalogAdminPassword": {
                            "value": "-::secureString"
                        }
                    },
                    "customSetupScriptProperties": {
                        "sasToken": {
                            "value": "-::secureString"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedInfo": {
                    "key": {
                        "value": "-::secureString"
                    },
                    "resourceId": "="
                },
                "computeProperties": {
                    "dataFlowProperties": {
                        "externalComputeInfo": [
                            {
                                "accessToken": "-::secureString"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers": {
        "properties": {
            "pipelines": [
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "*": "="
                    }
                },
                "pipelineReference.referenceName"
            ],
            "pipeline": {
                "parameters": {
                    "*": "="
                }
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "scope": "="
            }
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "accountName": "=",
                    "accountEndpoint": "=",
                    "username": "=",
                    "userName": "=",
                    "accessKeyId": "=",
                    "endpoint": "=",
                    "servicePrincipalId": "=",
                    "userId": "=",
                    "host": "=",
                    "clientId": "=",
                    "existingClusterId": "=",
                    "clusterUserName": "=",
                    "clusterSshUserName": "=",
                    "hostSubscriptionId": "=",
                    "clusterResourceGroup": "=",
                    "subscriptionId": "=",
                    "resourceGroupName": "=",
                    "tenant": "=",
                    "dataLakeStoreUri": "=",
                    "baseUrl": "=",
                    "database": "=",
                    "serviceEndpoint": "=",
                    "batchUri": "=",
                    "poolName": "=",
                    "databaseName": "=",
                    "systemNumber": "=",
                    "server": "=",
                    "url": "=",
                    "functionAppUrl": "=",
                    "environmentUrl": "=",
                    "aadResourceId": "=",
                    "sasUri": "|:-sasUri:secureString",
                    "sasToken": "|",
                    "connectionString": "|:-connectionString:secureString",
                    "hostKeyFingerprint": "=",
                    "mlWorkspaceName": "="
                }
            }
        },
        "Odbc": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "userName": "=",
                    "connectionString": {
                        "secretName": "="
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "folderPath": "=",
                    "fileName": "="
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "token": "="
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints": {
        "properties": {
            "privateLinkResourceId": "=",
            "groupId": "=",
            "fqdns": "="
        }
    },
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": {
        "properties": {
            "*": {
                "value": "="
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What shall I add ?

Answer (score 1):

Please open the {} symbol in from of the IR name and look through the properties
and then add them in the template under a section as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Please use this link : https://patrick-picard.medium.com/azure-data-factory-modifying-arm-template-parameters-53b11f38bced

Comment: "=" means copy the value , "-" means remove the value & so-on etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation but I'm not sure to understand what I'm sipposed to add in the template-parameters-definition.json file. I will edite the question to add the json description of my integration runtime

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this isn't precisely the answer you were looking for (you wanted to know what to put in the parameters file).  I couldn't find that answer when I looked, I don't think it's possible, unless something has changed recently.  What I did find, is that you can add a Powershell Script, at the start of your Deployment pipeline, that does a find and replace in your Template File, and replaces the name.  It doesn't seem ideal, but it works.  See the answer given here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/776353/how-can-we-parametrize-two-different-integration-r